# Jenkins node still asks for password after configuring ssh keys

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, ssh-keys

has anyone ever come across this issue?

So, I have a remote linux server I want to log into from a jenkins node (which is also a linux server).
To do that, I did the following steps:

1. I generated a ssh key pair in the jenkins node as jenkins user
2. I put the public key of the jenkins node in the authorized_keys of the remote server.
3. I created a credential in Jenkins using private key of the jenkins node generated as jenkins user.
4. I then created a script as below using sshagent.

Troubleshooting attempts

1. I configured ~/.ssh/config to use the key generated for jenkins user by remote hostname.
2. I tried restarting sshd service.
3. I made sure that jenkin user has permissions for the keys generated.

Problem:
The problem I am having is even after configuring keys, running ssh command still asks me for password.
So, I tried doing the same steps above, just generating keys with another user and running ssh comand, it does not ask for password and let me connect right away.

Could anyone help me out on why jenkins is not recognizing the private key? I've been trying to figuring out for days but I can't find the reason.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label '<jenkins node>'
    }

    environment {
        username = credentials('<remote_server_username>')
        server = '<remote_server>'
    }

    stages {
        stage('SSH into <remote_server> as <remote_server_username>') {
            steps {
                sshagent(['<jenkins_node_credentials>']) {
                    // some block
                    sh """ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l '${username_USR}' '$server' whoami"""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, assume you solved by now, but if not, try `sh """/usr/bin/ssh "${username_USR}@${server}" whoami"""`.

If still no luck, check /var/log/secure on the remote server - it could be permissions on the .ssh dir or authorized_keys